# Twig Template Include with blocks error

Tags: symfony, twig

I upgraded from Twig 1.x to 2.x and got bugged at the includes.

I will use the 'include' tag in the example below to demonstrate the intent I'm trying to describe.

```
#dashboard.html.twig
{# BREADCRUMB #}
{% include 'breadcrumb/breadcrumb.twig' with {pagetitle: block('pagetitle'), 
breadcrumb: block('breadcrumb')} %}
{# END BREADCRUMB #}

#breadcrumb.twig
<div class="row wrapper page-heading m-l-15">
    <h1 class="pagetitle">{{ pagetitle }}</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        {% autoescape false %}
            {{ breadcrumb }}
        {% endautoescape %}
        {% block breadcrumb %}
            <li>
                <a href="/">{{ 'homepage.menu.home'|trans }}</a>
            </li>
            {% if pagetitle %}
                <li class="active">
                    <strong>{{ pagetitle }}</strong>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    </ol>
</div>

#index.htlm.twig
{% extends 'dashboard.html.twig' %}
{% block pagetitle %}{{ 'meeting.rooms.list'|trans }}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{{ 'menu.management.meeting_rooms'|trans }}{% endblock %}
```

After updrage to twig I got the following error:
"Block "pagetitle" on template "dashboard.html.twig" does not exist."

Any suggestion or idea?

Comment: If so it also did not work in version 1.x.
To test I have already removed the pagetitle of the include:

`{% include 'breadcrumb/breadcrumb.twig' with {breadcrumb: block('breadcrumb')} %}`

e I got the following error: **Block "breadcrumb" on template "dashboard.html.twig" does not exist**"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the embed tag that combines the behaviour of include and extends for Twig 2.x.
[embed tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html)

Comment: Ok, then I've overridden the include by `{% embed "breadcrumb/breadcrumb.twig" with {pagetitle: block('pagetitle'), breadcrumb: block('breadcrumb')} %} {% endembed %}`

I've got the error: "Block "breadcrumb" on template "dashboard.html.twig" does not exist."

Is that what you suggested? :(